# Faster way than Spatial Join to join field from attribute table to address table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, census, address

I have a table of addresses for every state in the nation. I just recently finished doing spatial joins and adding in census block/tract data per state. I have a national shapefile of CoreBasedStatisticalAreas, is there a faster way to add one field from this attribute table to my completed address tables (millions of records) than doing Spatial Joins?

Comment: Have you tried *Join Field*?

Comment: There isn't really a common field between my address tables and the CBSA attribute table, therefore I was looking at a spatial join. Just need something faster.

Comment: Can you create a field based on a calculation or combination of attributes that you can use as a common field - or perhaps you have another table with a common field to your addresses and a common field to your CBSA data that you could use as daisy-chained join?

Comment: Ended up just intersecting my address points to the CBSA values then joining them back to the address table.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up just intersecting my address points to the CBSA values then joining them back to the address table.